# Excel Help on count and validation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have list of 200 people, also a list of 10 project contracts with a defined number of people to be allocated to each contract.

Now while allocating project contract across each resource, Can Excel trigger me with error - if I exceed number of resources for one particular project - Excel to trigger an error or dialog box -asking to correct the allocation.,

How can I do this?

see snapshot- i need the pivot to match base allowed data

[image: Picture]

Comment: Better share some source data & expected results with us for better understanding, will help us to fix the issue in better way !!

Comment: why `SUM()` of range of cells where number of people allocated for each project does not work for you?  I can not see from the question why plain sum doesn't do its job

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You can freely edit your own post but for your protection it must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you tried to edit without logging in, which shows up as an anonymous edit in a review queue.

Comment: The image is a start, but it isn't really clear what you mean by your description.  Can you elaborate on the rules behind this?  Walk us through your example.  Relate your terminology to cells in the example.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Srijith can you handle VBA macro,,, if  yes then I can suggest you the faster method to tack whether any cell value exceeds to particular number to create Alert Message !!

Answer (score 0):

**Since no where you have described the criteria *to check number of resources for particular project*.**

*Therefore I've assumed, that **the best suitable criteria should BILLING.***

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `J17`, fill it Down then Right.

  `=IF(SUMIFS($E$17:$E$24,$F$17:$F$24,$I17,$D$17:$D$24,J$16)>1,"Prj Exd.",SUMIFS($E$17:$E$24,$F$17:$F$24,$I17,$D$17:$D$24,J$16))`
- Apply Condition Formatting to highlight cell greater than 1.
- Use this Formula in Cell `J22`, fill it Down then Right. Also, Apply Conditional Formatting to highlight cell greater than 1.

  `=SUMIFS($E$17:$E$24,$F$17:$F$24,$I22,$C$17:$C$24,J$21)`
- *I'm sure this help you to fix the issue.*
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*